# Issues with SUBSTR function Oracle_SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I used the `SUBSTR` function for the similar purposes, but I encountered the following issue:

I am extracting 6 characters from the right, but the data in column is inconsistent and for some rows it has characters less than 6, i.e. 5 or 4. So for such rows, the function returns blanks. How can I fix this?

Example Scenario 1:

```
SUBSTR('0000123456',-6,6) 

Output: 123456
```

Scenario 2 (how do I fix this?, I need it to return '23456'):

```
SUBSTR('23456',-6,6)

Output: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression: if the string length is strictly greater than 6 then return just the last 6 characters; otherwise return the string itself. This way you don't need to call `substr` unless it is really needed.

Alternatively, if speed is not the biggest issue and you are allowed to use regular expressions, you can write this more compactly - select between 0 and 6 characters - as many as possible - at the end of the string.

Finally, if you don't mind using undocumented functions, you can use `reverse` and standard `substr` (starting from character 1 and extracting the first 6 characters; that will work as expected even if the string has length less than 6). So: reverse the string, extract first (up to) 6 characters, and then reverse again to restore the order. **WARNING**: This is shown only for fun; DO NOT USE THIS METHOD!

```
with
  test_data (str) as (
    select '0123449389' from dual union all
    select '00000000'   from dual union all
    select null         from dual union all
    select 'abcd'       from dual
  )
select str,
       case when length(str) > 6 then substr(str, -6) else str end as case_substr,
       regexp_substr(str, '.{0,6}$')        as regexp_substr,
       reverse(substr(reverse(str), 1, 6))  as rev_substr
from   test_data
;

STR          CASE_SUBSTR    REGEXP_SUBSTR  REV_SUBSTR
----------   -------------  -------------  --------------
0123449389   449389         449389         449389
00000000     000000         000000         000000
                                           
abcd         abcd           abcd           abcd
```

Comment: Lol Thanks  anyways. I ended up adjusting the length in the data model instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(substr('23456', -6, 6), '23456')
```

Another tweaks the length:

```
select substr('23456', greatest(- length('23456'), -6), 6)
```

Comment: I want to tweak the length,

Comment: I am using this SUBSTR function to extract just 6 characters from the column, but when there is a values less than 6 characters, which could be thousands,  it returns NULL